# Getting 404 Error in WordPress for the services only, on XAMPP local machine

Tags: wordpress, xampp, permalinks

I've been researching this error and can find similar issues but no solutions. I am running WordPress using XAMPP on my local server.

I imported a WordPress page and all was well. The problem is I added a bunch of new services, and when I try to access them I get a 404.

If I create a new post or page, they work fine. I reset the permalinks, no luck. The errors are only with the services. I'm really stuck on this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you explain what kind of  `services`? Did you mean the post type called services?

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant.

Comment: so the issue is with the post type?  Can you give a code sample for this post type's definition?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking for, I would have to assume that the issue has to be with the post type. Im semi-new to wordpress and assumed services were a part of all wordpress installations.. They may have come from ThemeRex Addons

Comment: The only post types that come with WordPress core are: post, page, revision, attachment, and nav_menu_item, others are defined through 3rd party plugins or themes ( defining withing theme is not recommended though). So I guess that this has been defined through ThemeRex add-on. You can easily search through code for `register_post_type` or `services` or `service`

Comment: You could try with this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156978/custom-post-type-single-page-returns-404-error